# Session object Not getting clear after log out when calling through postman

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a page when i login and then do f12 , i copy the request header , cookies and the request url and using post in postman i get the data.
After i logout and refersh the page again i use the same cookie in the postman and post the url data but i still get the data, even if i have done log out i still get the data.
I dont want to get any data after i logged out.i want the cookie to get expire or change when i logout.
If useing postman after logout should not return any data in the response.

Please help me.

Here is my logout code

Dim authCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName)
Dim authTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value)

```
        Session.Abandon()
        Session.Clear()
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    End If
    Session.Contents.Clear()
    Session.Clear()
    Session.RemoveAll()
    Session.Abandon()
    HttpContext.Session.Clear()
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
    Response.Expires = 60
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
 
    HttpContext.User = New GenericPrincipal(New GenericIdentity(String.Empty), Nothing)
    Response.Redirect(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("root").ToString() + "logon.aspx")
```